# What do I need to learn for a simple 3 stage webform?

Tags: javascript, sql, webforms, e-commerce

I'm not a developer, but savvy enough to look at HTML, CSS and PHP to know what it does and edit it when needed (using Google along the way, obviously).

So a friend and I had the idea to make a simple website which involves a simple 3 page webform that will need to post to a database. Pages 1 & 2 is just information, while page 3 will be a payments page on a secure server.

I wanted to know what I need to learn or look into to make pages 1 and 2 which are simple webforms with text fields that posts into a database, or really just posts the information to an email address even (I don't know how easy this is, so a DB would be fine).

I realise this might be a bit out of my league, but I really want to give it a try before giving up on it. I've got enough free time to read up and learn, but need to be pointed in the right direction.

The webform would use Javascript I imagine? and post into a database, so would that need SQL knowledge (I have 0 DB knowledge).

Any pointing in the right direction will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript by Robin Nixon.